# PHP PDO populating dropdown from large table in record edit form - pulling results from database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I'm learning PHP (and having great fun) but I've run up against a problem in a CRUD application that I can't seem to find a way around.

I need to use a dropdown for data entry on the create page. I also want to have the same dropdown on the update page, but of course this would need to set the value to the one already stored in the record when the update form loads. I have hand-coded some of the shorter dropdowns (see below) but the one I need to do next is 2008 records!! (it will be searched as input is typed).

I have looked at multiple posts about arrays etc and I can get the dropdown to list the values that way but can't figure out how to pull in the existing value.

The relevant code is as follows (please be gentle about the coding...I'm new!!):

```
<?php 
require_once "../includes/header.php";
?>

<?php
if ( isset($_POST['patient_id']) && isset($_POST['datadate'])
    && isset($_POST['bedspace']) && isset($_POST['episode_id']) ) {
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET patient_id = :patient_id,
         datadate = :datadate, bedspace = :bedspace, isadmitday = :isadmitday, antimicrobial = :antimicrobial
        WHERE episode_id = :episode_id";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':patient_id' => $_POST['patient_id'],
    ':datadate' => $_POST['datadate'],
    ':bedspace' => $_POST['bedspace'],
    ':episode_id' => $_POST['episode_id'],
    ':isadmitday' => $_POST['isadmitday'], 
    ':antimicrobial' => $_POST['antimicrobial']));
$_SESSION['success'] = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Record successfully updated</strong></div>';
header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
return;
}
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users where episode_id = :xyz");
$stmt->execute(array(":xyz" => $_GET['episode_id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ( $row === false ) {
$_SESSION['error'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">    <strong>Unable to proceed - bad episode_id value</strong></div';
header( 'episode_id: index.php' ) ;
return;
}
$n = htmlentities($row['patient_id']);
$e = htmlentities($row['datadate']);
$l = htmlentities($row['bedspace']);
$i = htmlentities($row['isadmitday']);
$am = htmlentities($row['antimicrobial']);
$episode_id = htmlentities($row['episode_id']);
?>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Edit episode record</h2><br>
                </div> <!-- /col-md-12 -->
            </div> <!-- /row -->
        </div> <!-- /row -->

        <div class="row">
            <form name="edit_record" id="edit_record" method="POST" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="patient_id" control-label>Patient ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patient_id"     name="patient_id" value="<?= $n ?>">
                </div> <!-- /form-group -->

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="datadate" control-label>Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datadate" name="datadate" value="<?= $e ?>">
                </div>  <!-- /form-group -->

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="bedspace" control-label>Bedspace</label>
                    <select class="form-control" required="required" id="bedspace" name="bedspace" value="<?= $l ?>">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="Side Ward 1" <?php echo $l == 'Side     Ward 1'?'selected':'';?>>Side Ward 1</option>
                        <option value="Bed 1" <?php echo $l == 'Bed   1'?'selected':'';?>>Bed 1</option>
                        <option value="Bed 2" <?php echo $l == 'Bed 2'?'selected':'';?>>Bed 2</option>
                        <option value="Bed 3" <?php echo $l == 'Bed 3'?'selected':'';?>>Bed 3</option>
                        <option value="Bed 4" <?php echo $l == 'Bed 4'?'selected':'';?>>Bed 4</option>
                        <option value="Bed 5" <?php echo $l == 'Bed 5'?'selected':'';?>>Bed 5</option>
                        <option value="Side Ward 2" <?php echo $l == 'Side Ward 2'?'selected':'';?>>Side Ward 2</option>
                        <option value="Side Ward 3" <?php echo $l == 'Side Ward 3'?'selected':'';?>>Side Ward 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>  <!-- /form-group -->
```

Comment: fyi, use: `require_once __DIR__ ."/../includes/header.php";` it will always work. i.e. doesn't matter what the 'current working directory' is set to as it an 'absolute path'. Remember this technique if you move the code to shared hosting.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any ideas on the dropdown issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after an intensive couple of days research I have things working like I want to, although I am sure my work-around isn't pretty! The dropdown is a list of antibiotc medicines called 'antimicrobials'. I have the dropdown list from the database using a SELECT statement and I am matching the value pulled from the other table to set the value of the dropdown when a record is edited.

The code below is from the edit.php file:

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['episode_id']) ) {
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET antimicrobial = :antimicrobial
        WHERE episode_id = :episode_id";
     $stmt=$PDO->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':antimicrobial' => $_POST['antimicrobial']));
    $_SESSION['success'] = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Record successfully updated</strong></div>';
    header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
return;
}

$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users where episode_id = :xyz");
$stmt->execute(array(":xyz" => $_GET['episode_id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ( $row === false ) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Unable to proceed - bad episode_id value</strong></div';
        header( 'episode_id: index.php' ) ;
    return;
    }

$am = htmlentities($row['antimicrobial']);    
$episode_id = htmlentities($row['episode_id']);

?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="antimicrobial" control-label>Antimicrobial from database</label>
    <?php
         $sql_am = 'SELECT antimicrobial FROM tbl_antimicrobials';
         $stmt_am = $PDO->query($sql_am);
    ?>
    <select class="form-control" id="antimicrobial"></select>
    <?php
        while ($row = $stmt_am->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
        $selected = ($row['antimicrobial'] == $am ) ? ' selected' : '';
        echo "<option value='" . $row['antimicrobial'] . "'" . $selected . ">" . $row['antimicrobial'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo '</select>';
    ?> 
</div> <!-- /form-group -->
```